# How to prevent undo from operating on invisible text/regions?

Tags: undo

**Q:** how can I prevent undos of invisible text?

I use `org-mode` and `outline-minor-mode` in virtually every
buffer, and leave text folded (invisible) unless I'm explicitly
working on it.  Sometimes I hide text and then accidentally hit
undo, which is super confusing.

How can I prevent `undo` from undoing edits that are in an
invisible part of the buffer?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to play with the built-in ability to undo/redo in region, and create a region that excludes the hidden text.